# Why i can not find Data profiling Task component in ssis?

Tags: ssis

I'm beginner in ssis ,want to use the data profile task in my project,read this tutorial:
[Data Profile task](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2854/using-the-data-profiling-sql-server-integration-services-ssis-task/)

but i can not find that component in my ssis,this is my ssis picture:
[image]

How can i add that component?thanks.

Comment: it sounds like you 're in the Data Flow tab , move to the Control Flow tab

Comment: @alex oh that's right my friend,please post your solution to i can vote up you,thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you 're in the Data Flow tab , move to the Control Flow tab, in this way you can find the necessary controls..